# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{} android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8:

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

Main Activity Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        initialize(new Library(), cfg);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-123456789/123456789");

        //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

        // Add a test device to show Test Ads
         .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
         .addTestDevice("CC5F2C72DF2B356BBF0DA198")
                .build();

        // Load ads into Banner Ads
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });

    }
    public void displayInterstitial() {
        // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Actvity Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-123456789/123456789" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Mainfest XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.neodots.Library"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

Error:

```
11-22 11:23:55.144: E/AndroidRuntime(955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.Library/com.neodots.Library.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
11-22 11:23:55.144: E/AndroidRuntime(955):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-22 11:23:55.144: E/AndroidRuntime(955):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-22 11:23:55.144: E/AndroidRuntime(955):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-22 11:23:55.144: E/AndroidRuntime(955):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-22 11:23:55.144: E/AndroidRuntime(955):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 11:23:55.144: E/AndroidRuntime(955):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

I am newbie to android coding, Using some tutorial i have wrote this codes.But now i am not able run my application due to bunch of errors .So can any one help me to resolve,Thank you in advance............................................................

Comment: I'm having similar errors due to the device being too old for the API being compiled. Have you modified your `build.gradle` file at all?

Comment: Emulator is not old. actually i am using libgdx,i dint find build.gradle in my project.Can you help how to setup that..

Comment: Have you referenced the google play services library in your project?

Comment: Yes.I followed procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't included the GooglePlayServices library in your APK. Since you are using a non-standard way of building, you will need to reference their docs on how to ensure that the GPS library is included in your APK.

Comment: I followed these steps  https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Sorry my bad. When I said "I followed some tutorial" and were using libgdx I assumed you were using some libgdx build mech. The important heading of that tutorial is "Add Google Play Services to Your Project". Make sure you are doing the right one for your environment. Are you using Android Studio, Eclipse, something else?